# How do I open Thursby SubRosa from another iOS App?

Tags: android, ios, smartcard

We have a mobile website that requires smart card authentication and is used on desktops, tablets, and on multiple operating systems. We'd like to create a shortcut on the iOS home screen for this mobile website, but the shortcut must open **Thursby SubRosa** (a smart card-enabled browser for iOS) and not Safari. So, if we create a small launcher iOS app, how would we open **Thursby SubRosa** and point it to a specific URL programmatically? Does SubRosa support "App Links" or "Deep Linking"?

Comment: You can't. The shortcut for home screen can only be a link made in Safari, thus, only able to launch in Safari.

Comment: It wouldn't be a shortcut, but rather a full iOS app whose only purpose would be to launch SubRosa.

Comment: full iOS app is not equal to *shortcut on the iOS home screen for this mobile website*

Answer (score 0):

if  Thursday SubRosa support custom scheme like  (thursbysubrosa://), you can redirect your webpage to this scheme. but it will open safari first. 
I think this is the only way to complete this

Answer (score 0):

pkardhttps:// for https

Email pkardsdk@thursby.com for questions